# How to change the name of the file downloaded through FileStreamResult in the C# web-api?

Tags: c#

This is my controller action. Basically I am preparing a CSV file in the WebAPI and from UI the file gets downloaded.

```cs
[HttpGet("GetCSV")]
public async Task<ActionResult<FileStreamResult>> GetCSV()
{
    var ret =  getfile();
    return Ok(ret);
}

public FileStreamResult getfile()
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        //some list

        string csv = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(list);

        stream = GenerateStreamFromString(csv);

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/csv");
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Flush();
    }
}

public MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    return stream;
}
```

The code works perfectly fine. From UI, when I call the WebAPI, the file gets downloaded in the name of GetCSV.csv.

The question is: How to change the name of the file?

Comment: You can try `return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/csv"){FileDownloadName = "iwouldlikethefilenamelikethis.csv"};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server must return a `Content-Disposition` header, in order for the client to know about an alternative file name:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somethingElse.csv"
```

`FileResult` returns this header when the FileDownloadName property is specified:

```
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/csv")
{
    FileDownloadName = "somethingElse.csv"
};
```

Comment: where to set the Content-Disposition?

Comment: You set the FileDownloadName property. The FileStreamResult class or one of its superclasses checks, if the FileDownloadName property has been specified. If it is, the method internally adds a Content-Disposition header to the result that includes the file name.  You cannot set the header directly.